# python interative mode does not work when reading from std in

Tags: python, bash, python-interactive

Given the following python script....

```
$ cat readStdin.py 
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

var = "".join(sys.stdin.readlines()).rstrip()
print var
```

... I get the follwing output:

```
$ echo hello  | python -i readStdin.py 
hello
>>> 
$
```

...  in other words it does not hang in the python console, but goes back to bash. Does anyone out there know how to make it stay in the python console???

Comment: This isn't an artifact of `python -i` not working (it works fine).  If you run your script without the shell pipeline it goes OK.  The problem is that the python tries to read more data from `echo` but that data doesn't exist, so it gets `EOF` immediately and closes (as I understand it).  Good question though ...

Comment: Agreed, this hasn't anything to do with interactive mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this -

```
$ echo print  4*2 | python -i
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 8
>>> 
$
```

Echo produces `print 4*2`. Python even in interactive mode, considers this as input to be interpreted. Hence we see the 8 there. After this, the interpreter encounters an `EOF`, so it quits. Consider what you press to quit the interpreter - `Ctrl+d` or `^D`. This is just another way to produce `EOF` on *nix.